# Execute bash script on multiple input files, ignoring other input variables

Tags: bash, automator

I'm using Mac's Automator to perform a bash script on files that are dropped onto a droplet. Inputs are gathered from Automator actions and are passed to a bash script as arguments. The script works with a single input file, but I'm having trouble handling multiple files.

My ultimate goal is to accept several dropped video files, prompt for a number, and extract that number of frames from each video file (using FFmpeg).

I can loop through inputs by using the special variable `$@`, like so:

```bash
for f in "$@"; do
    # perform an action
done
```

However, my script also prompts the user for text input that I don't want included in this loop.

I can access each input file individually by using `$1`, `$2`, etc. But I'd like to use a loop instead of referencing each file individually. Also, the quantity of input files is unpredictable and I'm not sure how to distinguish between input files and input text.

How can I loop through only the file inputs without including the text input?

Here is a description of my current workflow:

---

**Get Specified Movies**

> one.mov
>   two.mov

**Set Value of Variable** (accepts input)

> source_files

**Ask For Text** (ignores input)

> Enter a Number:

**Set Value of Variable** (accepts input)

> number

**Get Value of Variable** (ignores input)

> source_files

**Get Value of Variable** (accepts input)

> number

**Run Shell Script** (accepts input, pass "as arguments")

```bash
#/bin/bash

for f in "$@"; do
    echo $f
done
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

> /folder/one.mov
>   /folder/two.mov
>   8

I was hoping to have one variable set to the multiple inputs (so I could loop through it) and another variable set to the number, but it doesn't seem to work that way.

How can I loop through each input file without referencing the text input?

Comment: Are you just trying to find out how to test whether a given argument is an existing file?

Comment: That might be a solution. Do you think that's the best way? My ultimate goal is to accept several video files dropped onto a droplet, prompt for a number, and extract that number of frames from each video. I was hoping to have one variable set to the multiple inputs (so I could loop through it) and another variable set to the number, but it doesn't seem to work that way.

Comment: How many text input variables do you have? Only _number_?

Comment: @MarioZannone Yes, just one: *number*.

Comment: It can work that way if you stop using multiple scripts for this and/or use exported variables instead of arguments for communication between the scripts. That being said do you need the files as arguments at all? Wouldn't a directory of files to operate on be simpler?

Comment: @EtanReisner That sounds promising. What do you mean by "using multiple scripts"? How does one use "exported variables"? Processing files in a directory might be a solution. I was hoping to eventually handle any number of dropped items: a single video file, multiple video files, an entire directory. But I'm not quite there yet.

Comment: Your problem is that you have one script (I assume) which takes all the input and then calls another script with those values (from variables). Just stop using a second script and you have the values you need split into variables you can use directly, no?

Comment: @EtanReisner The inputs are gathered from Automator actions (`Get Specified Movies` and `Ask For Text`) and are passed to a bash script as arguments (`Run Shell Script`).

Comment: Ah. I misunderstood that. Then yes, the given answer is appropriate or look into real argument parsing in the script. Something like [Bash FAQ 035](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the order of the args: get value of variable `number` first, 
then get value of variable `source_files`, 
so that `number` will be the first parameter,

then:

```
echo number: $1
for f in "${@:2}"; do
    echo file: $f
done
```

Comment: Nice and simple. I guess I was making things more complicated than I needed to. `shift` is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Technically there's no need for `shift` here. You can use `"${@:2}"` instead. Look for `offset` in the [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) section of the bash reference manual.

Comment: @EtanReisner Hey, that's cool thanks. That way I don't need to destructively manipulate the original set of inputs. I appreciate the reference link, too.

Comment: @EtanReisner Agreed! I modified the sample code according to your suggestion.